# How to deselect h:selectManyListbox after submit

Tags: jsf, richfaces, selectmanylistbox

I am doing a project with jsf and richfaces. There is a selectManyList. After selection and saving in selectmanylist, SelectManyList is opened again. Last selected item is selected as default in list. However I want to prevent last selected item. How can I do?

```
                     <td valign="top">
                        <h:panelGroup id="ajaxAvailableProductPanel2">
                           <h:selectManyListbox
                            size="#{pc_ExternalProviderFrag.callServerBackingBean.availableProductsSelectItemsSize}"
                            id="availableProductsListbox2"
                            style="width: 100%;"
                            valueChangeListener="#{pc_ExternalProviderFrag.callServerBackingBean.handleAvailableProductsListboxValueChange}">
                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{pc_ExternalProviderFrag.callServerBackingBean.availableProductsSelectItems}" />
                           </h:selectManyListbox>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                     </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the component's value in action method.

So, given a

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
```

you can just do this in action method:

```
public void submit() {
    // ...

    selectedItems = null;
}
```

I have by the way the impression that the `valueChangeListener` doesn't belong there at all, but that's a different problem/question.

Comment: Thank you, but I am working confused a project. I can not see directly other code. However I try to that you said